# Creating duty list

Tags: algorithm

Assuming I have a list of workers, and a list of daily duties, and I want to generate a table for the coming month with workers assigned to duties, but I have to make sure it is "legal", meaning:

- A worker can't do more than one duty per day.
- A worker can't do duty without a two-day break between the last duty (If I cleaned the main office on Sunday, I wont do **any** duty on Monday and Tuesday.
- There are duties that only managers can do (though managers can also do any other duty, but there are some that only them can do).

I know it's not a simple question, but I'm looking for some guidance on how to approach this kind of problems.

Comment: Are the required duties the same every day?

Answer (score 0):

If the same duties need doing every day, the problem is relatively simple. You only need to calculate a three day schedule, and then repeat it as needed. The person who cleaned the main office on Sunday also cleans it on Wednesday, Saturday, and on Tuesday of the following week.

To build the three day schedule, first convert each duty into three tasks, one each for day 0, day 1, and day 2. Use [Bipartite Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) to associate a different person with each of those tasks. The graph will have a vertex for each person and for each task. Each person will be connected by an edge to each task anyone can do. Each manager also has an edge to each manager-only task.

If that problem does not have a solution including an edge to each task, there is no solution for the first three days of the original problem.